In a high voltage insulator with multiple discs, when is it advantageous to gradually increase their diameter?
What engineering considerations go into gradually increasing the diameter of dielectric discs for high voltage standoff insulators?
I recall seeing high voltage insulators that had small diameter discs at one end gradually increasing in diameter toward the other end.  However, I am having trouble finding support for my memory of such insulators, let alone the purpose of such gradation.  Since I don't know technical term for high voltage insulators that gradually vary the diameter of their dielectric discs, I provide this picture as it is the only one I could find via web search that was sourced (Shutterstock).  A better illustration is this image:

I found on LinkedIn for which I haven't found a source other than the post there which seemed to get it from somewhere else.


James Bowery - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the name & link (URL) to the webpage where that image originated, so not a Google Images link (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). TY (It doesn't apply here, but for offline sources e.g. book, give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition.)

James, so many things come to mind. These are solids and air and placed in a variety of circumstances. But at bottom are details of the field strength in the air around it, I think. That doesn't help me suggest a reason for that specific shape. What did pop to mind is light -- particularly UV light from the sun. 295nm and 325nm for Argon may be the worst worry. But I'm just offering a random thought. I'm sure the design takes into account many factors I'm simply ignorant of. Were it me, I'd find a plasma physics professor and just write to them. They do respond (to me in the past, anyway.)

James, in case it helps, back in 2001 I wrote to John P. Verboncoeur, at the time the "Associate Professor in Residence" at the Nuclear Engineering Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Sciences, University of California, Berkeley, CA 94720-1770. He was very quick to respond and to help out. I'd like to suggest that you contact that department and see if someone there is willing to help you. My guess is that the answer will be yes and that you will enjoy the help you receive from them.
